# Multiple consumers working as single consumer with Masstransit

Tags: masstransit

My system has a constrain for specific consumer that messages should be handled in order, one after the other. To implement that we set the concurrency to 1.
Now we want to scale out and add more instance of this consumer.
To keep the order I want to use distributed lock manager like 'RedLock'. It can tell each consumer if it is OK to fetch the next message.

I work with RabbitMq and my question is if there is kind of observer event that comes before getting messages from the queue. In other words I need a way to enable/disable the operation of polling messages from the queue.

Comment: Do you have a unique identifier that can be used to partition the workload to maintain order within the same partition? If not, you can't maintain order and distribute across workers.

Comment: I have unique identifier for each message. I didn't understand how can I maintain order. Thanks.